# How to generate mouse events with pressure?

Tags: java

I want to emulate wacom tablet in such way, that different apps like photoshop will resive my mouse events with pressure. How can I do it?

Comment: Despite extensions, you'd most probably need to implement natively, unless you have such a special HID, this is not going to work anyway. A regular mouse, and the events in Java, have binary buttons only (state 1 or 0; true, or false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java API is oriented to normal mouse events. Using a mouse device does not give you a sense of pressure, as the device does not provide such input. If a normal mouse is your input device, then you have no way to get such info.

You could however imitate such input functionality, using the **time interval** of the mouse button being clicked. I would suggest using the "key down" and the "key up" event of the mouse click and translate the time difference between them as an indicator of the "pressure". Perhaps [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) tutorial could give you some guidance.

Another idea would be to get somehow info from the device directly. You could use the [device API](http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/) to get direct input and wrap it in your application.

Hope I helped!